# undefined method `numbers' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Building a simple phone book app and have a concern regarding the following:

Each of my listed contacts has a number resource, and their relationship is defined in the routes file as follows:

```
config/routes.rb
resources :contacts do
    resources :numbers
  end
```

In my webapp thus far, I have it so that a user can create a contact and then create a number corresponding with that contact. I list the numbers for the contact, and when the user clicks on it (in order to route to the numbers#show page for that specific number, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in NumbersController#show
undefined method `numbers' for nil:NilClass
```

I've had this error a ton of times, and always it happened because the contact wasn't instantiated properly. But in my code, everything is being saved to db properly as per my rails console exploration. Below is the code throwing the error, found inside my numbers controller:

```
def set_number #to do item
      @number = @contact.numbers.find(params[:id])
    end
```

And the parameters being passed in, according to the error page, are the following:

```
Parameters:

{"contact_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

I set @contact via this method in the numbers controller:

```
def set_contact 
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
end
```

and I call it at the top as so:

```
  before_action :set_contact
```

Given that there are parameters, and Rails console tells me both the contact and the number were saved properly, any idea what's wrong?

Comment: can you actually just post the entire numbers controller as well as the link the user is clicking that is raising the error?

Comment: You have to have your `before_action :set_contact` before your `before_action :set_number`, otherwise you won't have the `@contact` when calling the `:set_number`

Comment: `@number = Number.find(params[:id])` is enough, you don't have to look into `@contact` to find the `number`

Comment: Hi @dpedoneze, your answer was the first correct one. Please put it as an answer below and I'll mark as correct. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted as a comment:

You have to have your `before_action :set_contact` before your `before_action :set_number`, otherwise you won't have the `@contact` when calling the `:set_number`.

All the `before_action` runs in the order that you added them :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the error seems to be in `set_number` method inside your controller. And the reason is `@contact` is nil.

So, as in above comments, your `set_contact` method may be running after `set_number`